# ncurses not colored ansi input from fifo

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

colorized input string from fifo file not in color in ncuses terminal.

in C code:

```
if ( (mainwin = initscr()) == NULL ) {
printf("Error initialising ncurses.\n");  return 1;
}
termwin  = subwin(mainwin, LINES-5, COLS, 2, 0);
while(... read the file) {
waddstr(termwin, p);
wrefresh(termwin);
}
```

output visual string:

```
^[[0;33;6m38701^[[0m
```

where set terminal in ncurses to correct ANSI color translate?

programm is printed to fifo use:

```
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
```

Comment: Does your file literally have the string `^[`?  Or does it correctly have a non-printable byte with the value 27 (0x1b)?

Comment: Use [ncurses colors](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/color.html).

Comment: Where use ncurses color in another programm ? Only access to fifo fail, read & write. If test, printf(..) good view colorize string, so no write in selected ncurses window...